CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET does not take an effect with iOS
According to this post I specified CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in my CMake as follows:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3)

if (APPLE)
    #The variable CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET must initialized as a cache variable prior to the first project() command
    if(IOS)
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0" CACHE STRING "Minimum iOS deployment version")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "11.0" CACHE STRING "Minimum MacOS deployment version")
    endif()
endif()

project(MyApp LANGUAGES CXX)

and run CMake with XCode generator.
With MacOS this generates correct MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in XCode project, but with iOS it has no effect and IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0 is generated in XCode project, while according to docs it should also apply to iOS.
My CMake version is 3.29.2, XCode version is 15.3.
EDIT1
Tried to set CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET as cashed and non cashed:
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0" CACHE STRING "Workaround for minimum iOS deployment version")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0")

but it did not help, the only working workaround is:
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0")

EDIT2
Tried the code from the answer:
if (APPLE)
    # The variable CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET must initialized as a cache variable prior to the first project() command
    # Your code won't work the variable IOS cannot be used before the project call. It will always be false.
    # You must use the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME instead
    message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
    if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "iOS")
        #Does not take an effect, the workaround is setting XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0" CACHE STRING "Minimum iOS deployment version")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "11.0" CACHE STRING "Minimum MacOS deployment version")
    endif()
    message("CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET has been set to ${CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
endif()

but got the following output:

I restarted QT Creator, run CMake and got this:

but when I deleted build files and run a clean CMake I got it again:

QT Creator specifies the following OSX attributes:

but not CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.

I think setting the env-vars MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET or IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET will probably work.

Setting the cache entry by default does NOT overwrite the existing value. Are you sure the cache var was not already defined? Or, would adding FORCE to the set statements make any difference?

Independently of my comment above, are you sure that there is no normal variable with the same name that shadows the cache variable?

@gordan.sikic I tried to set CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET as cashed and non cashed separately (commenting one line and uncommenting other)

Do not use screenshots. All of this can be copied as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Your code won't work the variable IOS cannot be used before the project call. It will always be false.
The project call is responsible for quite a lot. It's worth understanding what it does so you can reason about these scenarios. The project call is where CMake finally determines the platform you are targeting, compilers, etc.
You'll need to make a toolchain file that specifies the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME and the CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.
Example:
# Name this file iOS.cmake
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "iOS")
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "14.0" CACHE STRING "Minimum iOS deployment version" FORCE)

Then you can use this file like so:
cmake -S . -B build/ -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=iOS.cmake

CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is empty in my environment for some reason, in updated post I provided my CMake code.

From the CMake docs cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-ios-tvos-visionos-or-watchos. You need to set the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.

I restarted QT Creator and got CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS

I've made an MR to CMake to help clarify the documentation for IOS to help users in the future: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/9491

@AlexeyStarinsky please ignore my previous advise. I'm still correct that your previous usage of the IOS variable was incorrect. See this discussion https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/9491#note_1518881

I've updated the answer after talking to various CMake maintainers.
